# A python script to download any file on the internet

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, python-module, pywin32

I have a python script to download any file from the internet. I am encountering an error.

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/PacY/PycharmProjects/filedownload/downloadfile.py", line 5, in 
with open('C:/Users/PacY/Downloads', 'wb') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/PacY/Downloads'*

Below is the code.

````
link = input("Enter Url to be downloaded:")
file_url = requests.get(link)
with open('C:/Users/PacY/Downloads', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(file_url.content)```


I can't figure out why it's not working.

Thank you in advance for your help.
````

Comment: You are opening a folder and not a file. You need to specify the filename as well. For example: "with open("'C:/Users/PacY/Downloads/file.jpg'...).

Answer (score 0):

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/PacY/Downloads'

This error message means that you cannot open the path `C:/Users/PacY/Downloads` as a file for writing.

There's two components to that: you are trying to open the path `C:/Users/PacY/Downloads`

- as a *file*
- for *writing*

So, just by common sense, there are two possible reasons why that might fail:

- it is not a file
- it is not writable by you (and there are again two possible reasons for this)

  - it is not writable *at all* (for example, it is on a CD-ROM or a write-protected disk)
  - it is not writable *by you specifically* (i.e. you don't have write permissions)

We don't know what your system looks like, so we can't tell which of those possibilities is the root cause. However, *assuming* that you have a standard Windows setup, it is highly likely that `C:/Users/PacY/Downloads` is a directory, not a file, and *that* is the reason why it cannot be opened as a file.